# How to deserialize inherited Kotlin data classes with Gson

Tags: json, inheritance, gson, kotlin, data-class

In an Android App I need to deserialize Json data for Kotlin data classes, with a single abstraction level. But I don't have any idea, to place correct properties in constructors.

As a simple version, let's say I have a Shape:

```
abstract class Shape(open val x: Int, open val y: Int)
```

with two derivations

```
data class Circle(val radius: Int, override val x: Int, override val y: Int): Shape(x, y)
```

and

```
data class Square(val width: Int, override val x: Int, override val y: Int): Shape(x, y)
```

So my target is, not to instantiate a Shape. So, instead always deserialize its derivations. Later I need to handle some collection properties in other classes like:

```
val shapes: List<Shape>
```

but I also have to know the derived type of each element.

When I try to deserialize the given example with Gson

```
val square = gson.fromJson(SQUARE_JSON, Square::class.java)
```

I always get an IllegalArgumentException

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.example.shapes.model.Square declares multiple JSON fields named x

at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:886)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
```

Is there any possibility to deserialize this classes correctly without writing a custom Gson TypeAdapter or loosing data class advantages?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Both `Shape` and `Square` declare fields `x` and `y`. An instance of `Square` actually stores the value for `x` and `y` twice. To avoid this you can remove `x` and `y` from the `Shape` constructor and declare them as `abstract`. The same goes for `Circle` e.g.:

```
abstract class Shape {
    abstract val x: Int
    abstract val y: Int
}

data class Circle(val radius: Int, override val x: Int, override val y: Int) : Shape()

data class Square(val width: Int, override val x: Int, override val y: Int) : Shape()
```

Gson will now be able to successfully serialize and deserialize `Circle` and `Square` objects.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not able to convert the base class to Kotlin just yet, the `@Transient` annotation worked for me.

```
data class Circle(val radius: Int, 
    @Transient val x: Int, 
    @Transient val y: Int): Shape(x, y)

data class Square(val width: Int, 
    @Transient val x: Int, 
    @Transient val y: Int): Shape(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is Gson  problem with data classes? It should work with them correctly, only non nullable fields may be a problem.

Your error indicates that you have fields with same name in it.
If there's any particular field you don't want to include you have to annotate it with `@Transient`